# Acer H277H monitor is not charging 2016 MacBook when plugged in via USB-C. Is this possible?

Tags: display, usb, battery, charging

My MacBook is connected to monitor via computer's USB-C to monitor's Display Port with one cable. Given that MacBook only has one USB-C port, my computer cannot charge while using the monitor. If the computer is not charging the display will shut off when the MacBook's lid is closed thus requiring me to leave the lid open, which is, in turn, draining power quickly.

Is there a way to power the computer via the monitor while plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a USB-C compliant monitor so it's not going to supply power.<sup>1</sup>  DVI, DP, and HDMI don't support power delivery.  Looking at the [Tech Specs page](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.HH7AA.001) for this monitor, it supports:

- DVI
- HDMI
- VGA

To charge your MacBook **and** connect your external monitor, you need something like the [Apple USB-C Multiport AV adapter](http://radnex.us/apple-usbc-multiport-av-adapter).

[image]

So, you won't be able to charge your MacBook via this monitor because your monitor doesn't support power delivery, but you can have both your monitor and power adapter connected by using this adapter.

---

<sup>1</sup> USB-C Power Delivery Specification.  http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/